# Foreach loop for comments with nested comments

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a challenge for a commenting system with replays on comments. And I'm trying to add the nested replays correct in the original replay.

So I have this array:

```
$comments =  Array(
Array (
    "reactieID" => "1",
    "parent_reactieID" => "-1",
    "reactiePoster" => "User 1",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-27 15:38:25",
    "reactieBericht" => "Single comment 1",
    "HasChild" => "False",
), Array
(
    "reactieID" => "2",
    "parent_reactieID" => "-1",
    "reactiePoster" => "User 2",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-24 15:18:25",
    "reactieBericht" => "Single comment 2",
    "HasChild" => "False",
),Array
(
    "reactieID" => "3",
    "parent_reactieID" => "-1",
    "reactiePoster" => "User 3",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-22 17:09:12",
    "reactieBericht" => "Reaction with replay",
    "HasChild" => "True",
),Array
(
    "reactieID" => "4",
    "parent_reactieID" => "3",
    "reactiePoster" => "Replay 1",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-24 15:18:18",
    "reactieBericht" => "Message 1 for replay on ID 3",
    "HasChild" => "False",
),Array
(
    "reactieID" => "5",
    "parent_reactieID" => "3",
    "reactiePoster" => "Replay 2",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-24 15:19:18",
    "reactieBericht" => "Message 2 for replay on ID 3",
    "HasChild" => "False",
),Array
(
    "reactieID" => "6",
    "parent_reactieID" => "-1",
    "reactiePoster" => "User 4",
    "reactieDatum" => "2023-03-21 15:38:25",
    "reactieBericht" => "Single comment 4",
    "HasChild" => "False",
));
```

HasChild and parent_reactieID are doing the tricks for finding single comments and comments with nested replays.

My foreach for now is as follows:

```
foreach($comments as $cl) {
    if ($cl["HasChild"] == 'True' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] = -1) {
        echo ' Has Child '.  $cl["reactieID"].PHP_EOL.'';
    } elseif ($cl["HasChild"] == 'False' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] != -1) {
        echo ' is Child '.  $cl["reactieID"].PHP_EOL.'';
    } elseif ($cl["HasChild"] == 'False' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] = -1) {
        echo ' single comment '.  $cl["reactieID"].PHP_EOL.'';
    }
}
```

And this is the (simplified) output I now have:
single comment 1

single comment 2

Has Child 3

is Child 4

is Child 5

single comment 6

But in the HTML layout (bootstrap 5) it is needed to nest the replays, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Below is the desired HTML output:

```
<!-- Comments -->
<section>
    <h4 class="fw-bolder mb-1"><?php echo $db->count_comment($nieuwsid).' '. $db->name($nieuwsid);?></h4>
    <div class="card bg-light mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <!-- Single comment ID 1-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 1&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 1 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-27 15:38:25</span>
                    </div>
                    Single comment 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Single comment ID 2-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 2&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 2 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-24 15:18:25</span>
                    </div>
                    Single comment 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Comment with nested comments ID 3-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <!-- Parent comment-->
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 3&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 3 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-22 17:09:12</span>

                    </div>
                    Reaction with replay
                    <!-- Child comment 1 ID 4-->
                    <div class="d-flex mt-4">
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                                src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=Replay 1&rounded=true&size=50"
                                alt="..." /></div>
                        <div class="ms-3">
                            <div class="fw-bold">Replay 1 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-24 15:18:18</span>

                            </div>
                            Message 2 for replay on ID 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Child comment 2 ID 5-->
                    <div class="d-flex mt-4">
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                                src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=Replay 2&rounded=true&size=50"
                                alt="..." /></div>
                        <div class="ms-3">
                            <div class="fw-bold">Replay 2 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-24 15:19:18</span>

                            </div>
                            Message 2 for replay on ID 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Single comment ID 6-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 4&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 4 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-27 15:38:25</span>
                    </div>
                    Single comment 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is your input already sorted (ie so all the replies to a specific comment are together)?  Is it only one level deep?

Comment: Yes the array is already sorted and it is one level deep. The foreach in my question is as far as I have.

Comment: Then just use the basic structure you have to output the HTML you want.  The only fiddly bit is that you'll need to keep a lagging variable (maybe $lastType) that corresponds to the last rendered item and check this at the top of your loop to see if any divs need closing before outputting the next item. (Oh, and at the end of your loop too)

Comment: Oke thanks for the response. I will focus on finding the last nested item.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You'll need to update the HTML to include your data, but this might give you a start....

$lastType = null;
foreach($comments as $cl) {
    if ($cl["HasChild"] == 'True' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] = -1) {

        // has child

        ?>
            <!-- Comment with nested comments ID 3-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <!-- Parent comment-->
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 3&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 3 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-22 17:09:12</span>

                    </div>
                    Reaction with replay
        <?php
        $lastType = 'has child';

    } elseif ($cl["HasChild"] == 'False' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] != -1) {

        // is child

        switch ($lastType) {
            case 'has child':
            case 'is child':
                echo '</div></div>';
                break;
        }
        ?>

            <!-- Child comment 2 ID 5-->
            <div class="d-flex mt-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=Replay 2&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">Replay 2 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-24 15:19:18</span>

                    </div>
                    Message 2 for replay on ID 3
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
        $lastType = 'is child';

    } elseif ($cl["HasChild"] == 'False' && $cl["parent_reactieID"] = -1) {

        // single comment

        switch ($lastType) {
            case 'has child':
            case 'is child':
                echo '</div></div>';
                break;
        }
        ?>
            <!-- Single comment ID 1-->
            <div class="d-flex mb-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0"><img class="rounded-circle"
                        src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&name=User 1&rounded=true&size=50"
                        alt="..." /></div>
                <div class="ms-3">
                    <div class="fw-bold">User 1 <span class="text-muted fw-normal">2023-03-27 15:38:25</span>
                    </div>
                    Single comment 1
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
        $lastType = 'single comment';
    }
}

switch ($lastType) {
    case 'has child':
    case 'is child':
        echo '</div></div>';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I couldn't figure out how to find the last nested item in the foreach loop, so I added a field for selecting the last item in MySQL, and from there on I added if ($cl["reactieID"] == $cl["LastReplay"]) { in the foreach loop to find the last item.